# Website to get ideas for trick photography

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, digital, trick-photography

Are there some good websites which I can refer to for doing trick photography?
As of now, I am looking at photography with a snow theme, but it could be anything.

For example, a couple taking each others picture using 2 cameras.

I have some ideas in my mind, but any sample photos would really help me in visualizing.

I am open to doing editing using Photoshop after shooting the pics.

Comment: your-favorite-search-engine image search or Flickr perhaps might be a good place to start.  Helps to show that you've made an effort, and if the results of your search are disappointing, *then* ask for help.

Answer (score 4):

While your question is very vague (and in danger of being closed)

I would take a look at http://www.diyphotography.net/

It has all sorts of ideas and unusual "trick" things to do that are a bit more interesting than pointing a camera at a cow!

Answer (score 3):

take a look at http://trickphotographybook.com/ just scroll down and you will see a lot of trick photos that can get you inspired. The same guy runs a youtube channel where he explains much of his work. The channel name is the same as the website : http://photoextremist.com/ namely http://www.youtube.com/user/PhotoExtremist